# JavaFX-Launcher? logger level

Tags: java, gradle, logging

Well, I changed my project from maven to gradle to be able to use some plugins that I can't find in maven.
Since the moment I changed it, some logging messages are showing in the console.
It seems they are from JavaFX Launcher, but I don't know how to turn them off.

```
10:20:50.085 [JavaFX-Launcher] INFO net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Configurator -- ical4j.properties not found.
ago 24, 2023 10:20:49 A.�M. com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2efff350'
10:20:51.484 [JavaFX-Launcher] INFO org.hibernate.Version -- HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
```

This are some of them but there are lots of info messages. I haven't changed anything besides the build tool.
Any idea where are they coming from and how to change its level?
Thank you!

Comment: "I haven't changed anything besides the build tool". So, you mean you have changed your whole dependency management, and the way your resources and configurations are included.

Comment: Yes, but no code or logging properties file, so my first thought was that it is something related to gradle, but I can't find any logging reference in it

Comment: Gradle doesn't directly affect your logging. The libraries and their versions might, or which configuration file is found first.